# Homotopy equivalence and top deRham cohomology group of closed disk

Tags: de-rham-cohomology

On one hand, a closed disk $D^2$ is contractible so that it has the same cohomology as a point, so $H^2(D^2)=0$.

On the other hand, $D^2$ is a compact orientable manifold (isn't it?). According to [Top deRham cohomology group of a compact orientable manifold is 1-dimensional](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228502/top-derham-cohomology-group-of-a-compact-orientable-manifold-is-1-dimensional), $H^2(D^2)\cong\mathbb R$ and I got a conflict.

Where am I wrong? I guess "$H^n(M)\cong\mathbb R$ where $M$ is a compact orientable smooth manifold of dimension n" is not applicable to a manifold with boundary?